# How do I make an image provided by an api as the background image of my div in jQuery and node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I am trying to create a search engine for movies with an api provided by the movie database (tmdbs). I want to have a div popup for each movie that has a title similar to the one the user types in to the database. Right now I chose the movie Lucy as my experiment. I want the poster image provided in the first result of the api when I search for Lucy to be the background image of the div I am creating, I cannot seem to be able to accomplish this. My ultimate goal is to create a series of results with divs that have background images as provided by the first 20 results in the api. Here is my code:

```
$('#search').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var movie = $('#search-input').val();
            $('form#login').submit();
            console.log('onclick fun', movie)
            makeCall(movie);
            return false;
        }
    });

    function makeCall(aMovie) {
        console.log('makecall', aMovie);

        link = url + aMovie;
        console.log(link);
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: link,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("the data -->", data);
                getData(data);
            },
        })
    }

    function getData(responseData) {
        var poster = responseData.results[0].poster_path;
        appendToDom(poster);
    }

    function appendToDom(poster) {
        var aPoster = $('<div>');
        var movie_poster = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280' + poster;
        console.log(movie_poster);
        aPoster.css({
            'float': 'left',
            'margin': 10,
            'margin-left': 37,
            'margin-top': 20,
            'width': 200,
            'height': 300,
            'font-size': 36,
            'color': 'black',
            'background-size': '200px 300px',
            'background-image': 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/rwn876MeqienhOVSSjtUPnwxn0Z.jpg' //'url("./../images/question.jpg")'
        })
        $(main).append(aPoster);
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of what I'm looking for. Instead of the question marks I want the movie posters to come up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmGC0.png)

I'm really sorry for the long post. I hope someone can help me:)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `'background-image': 'url(your url goes here)'`

Answer (score 0):

var aPoster = $('');

and

var aPoster = $('div');

return totally different values. Might want to check that.